# recuperar valor de una columna calculada en SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2017

Como indica el título, quisiera saber si existe alguna manera en la que pueda recuperar el valor de una columna previamente calculada en un select y utilizar ese valor.
digamos algo asi:

```
SELECT 
ID, 
CODIGO, 
DESCRIPCION, 
COSTO,
COSTO * 1.5 AS PRECIODEVENTA,
PRECIODEVENTA * .8 AS PRECIOCLIENTE1,
PRECIODEVENTA * .9 AS PRECIOCLIENTE2
FROM PRODUCTOS
```

Answer (score 1):

Directamente no, pero existen al menos tres alternativas simples.

El escenario:

```
Create table dbo.Productos
(id int, codigo varchar(10), descripcion varchar(20), Costo float)

Insert into dbo.Productos(id, codigo, descripcion, Costo)
values
(1,'cod1','Prod1',100.54),
(2,'cod2','Prod2',50.25);
```

**Opción 1. Cte**

Si envuelves la consulta en una tabla de expresión común, en la salida puedes acceder al alias de la columna para calcular los siguientes valores.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Productos.id
         , Productos.codigo
         , Productos.descripcion
         , Productos.Costo
         , Productos.Costo * 1.5 as PrecioVenta
           FROM dbo.Productos
)
Select CTE.id,
    CTE.codigo,
    CTE.descripcion,
    CTE.Costo,
    CTE.PrecioVenta,
    CTE.PrecioVenta * .8 AS PRECIOCLIENTE1,
    CTE.PrecioVenta * .9 AS PRECIOCLIENTE2
from CTE;
```

[image: res1]

**Opción 2. Tabla derivada**

De la misma forma que lo envuelves en una cte, puedes usar una tabla derivada.

```
SELECT D.*,
    D.PrecioVenta * .8 AS PRECIOCLIENTE1,
    D.PrecioVenta * .9 AS PRECIOCLIENTE2
FROM (
    SELECT Productos.id
        , Productos.codigo
        , Productos.descripcion
        , Productos.Costo
        , Productos.Costo * 1.5 as PrecioVenta
          FROM dbo.Productos
    ) AS D
```

[image: res2]

**Opción 3. Operador apply**

Si a la tabla le publicas un alias, puedes usar el operador apply para acceder a un cálculo de la columna.

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.codigo
     , p.descripcion
     , p.Costo
     , Precios.PV as PrecioVenta
     , Precios.PV * .8 AS PRECIOCLIENTE1
     , Precios.pv * .9 AS PRECIOCLIENTE2
       FROM dbo.Productos p
       CROSS APPLY
       (SELECT p.Costo*1.5 AS PV ) AS Precios;
```

[image: Res3]